# Angular 2 getting "Error: Cannot match any routes: ''"

Tags: angularjs, angular

In my Angular 2 app (RC4), when the index.html opens, 
I get the error Error: Cannot match any routes: ''
I know this has been asked before, but none of the answers in those cases seems to apply to me; that is, I"m already doing everything recommended to fix this.
I have

```
<base href="/">
```

in my head element (also tried

```
<base href=".">
```

which makes no difference at all).
I have the following in my app.route.ts:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/instruction-steps', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
  { path: 'find-and-replace', component: FindAndReplaceComponent },
  { path: 'instruction-steps', component: InstructionStepsComponent }
];
```

The page does render correctly, and my routes to the other views work. If I reload the page, however, I'll not only get the error, but the page does not render.

This is running on lite-server, not ASP.NET.

Comment: Did you try removing the `/` of `/instruction-steps`?

Answer (score 0):

i can not comment due to low reputation points but are you using angular 2 with asp.net then you have to add code in startup.cs that point to use index.html when no route found.

Comment: Not using ASP.NET. Clarified in original question.

Comment: @RikkiAbe I am also facing the similar issue and have tried everything, did you find any fix to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips to watch out for:

1. Be sure that modules are properly defined as `@NgModule`.
2. Be sure that routing modules are properly added to imports for the module.
3. Be sure that paths are spelled correctly (e.g. "item" vs. "items")
4. Be sure that each module is added to the main App Module.

Please note that this is as of the Final release of Angular 2.