# Cannot match any routes: ""

Tags: javascript, html, angular, router, angular-routing

app.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { PushComponent }      from './push/push.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'push',  component: PushComponent}
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
     <h1>{{title}}</h1>
     <nav>        
        <a [routerLink]="['/push']">push1</a> 
        <a [routerLink]="['/push']">push2</a> 
     </nav>

      <nav>
      <a routerLink="/push" routerLinkActive="active">push3</a>
      <a routerLink="/push" routerLinkActive="active">push4</a>
    </nav>

     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   `,
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

push.component.ts

```
@Component({
    // selector: 'push-comp',
    template:
      //   `<form (submit)="submitForm()">
      //   <input [(ngModel)]="element.name"/>
      //
      //   <button type="submit">Submit the form</button>
      // </form>
      // <br>
    `<button (click)="getHeroes()"> get </button> <button (click)="saveHeroes()"> push </button>`,
    // templateUrl: 'app/html/heroes.component.html',
    providers: [PushService]
})
export class PushComponent implements OnInit {
    pushResult:PushResult;
    // selectedHero:Hero;
    // addingHero = false;
    error:any;
    element:any;
```

but I have 2 errors:

1) I don't see the template (2 buttons) from the push component

2) I get an error `Cannot match any routes: ''` from the chrome browser, but i don't know where is the link to `''`

I have see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488539/angular-2-getting-error-cannot-match-any-routes), but I already have in index.html:

`<head>
  <base href="/">`

Comment: You get this error when you click one of the router links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route '' is your default route. You can add default route like this-

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/push', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'push',  component: PushComponent}
];
```

See if this helps.